# Loading Screen doesn't show when pagination is clicked but the code works fine on other views

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a strange problem in my Angular Webapp. I put in a loading screen that works fine on all views but the search view, but I'm using the same code logic in all of them :/
I tried creating a plunker for you but it works fine there, too. My error must be directly in my search view code.

I have pagination and when I click on a different page there should be a loading screen again, but it doesn't show up (It does show on the initial page loading though, just never again after that). My helper variable `loaded` is modified correctly after clicking on a page. I have another view just like that with pagination where it works fine, and I'm not doing anything very different there. On both views I call a `loadpage(p)` function and there I set my `loaded` to `false` and then to `true` again after everything is done.

*I also don't think that my search is too "fast" for the loading screen to show up, because my smartphone needs 2-3 seconds to load the pages.*

Here is a [Link](http://zoiglapp.bplaced.net/#/search/a) to the page of my current live version of the app, where the problem appears.

Here is my html:

```
<img ng-if="!loaded" ng-src="images/SplashScreen.gif" />
<div ng-class="{load: !loaded}">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
        <li ng-repeat="p in pages()" ng-click="loadpage(p)"><a href="">{{p}}</a></li>
    </ul>
    <uib-accordion close-others="true"> 
        <uib-accordion-group is-open="isopen" ng-repeat="pub in cutPubs">
            [....]
        </uib-accordion-group>
    </uib-accordion>
</div>
```

And my Controller:

```
app.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$filter', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $filter) {
    //Read searchterm
    $scope.st = $routeParams.searchterm;
    //Create Pub Arrays
    $scope.filteredPubs = [];
    $scope.cutPubs = [];
    //Helpers
    $scope.currentpage = 1;
    $scope.noresults = false;
    $scope.loaded = false;

    $http.get("data/selectPubsSearch.php")
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.pubs = data;
        $scope.filteredPubs = $filter('search')($scope.pubs, $scope.st);
        $scope.pagecount = Math.ceil($scope.filteredPubs.length/20); 

        //Pagination Loop
        $scope.pages = function() {
            var input = [];
            for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.pagecount; i++) {
                input.push(i);
            }
            return input;
        };

        //Cut off results into units of 20 for pages
        $scope.cutArray = function(offset) {    
            $scope.cutPubs = [];
            for (var i = offset; i < $scope.filteredPubs.length && i < offset+20;  i++) {
                $scope.cutPubs.push($scope.filteredPubs[i]);
            }
            $scope.loaded = true;
        };
        $scope.cutArray(0); //call for initial page load

        //Load and insert the page specific content
        $scope.loadpage = function(page) {
            $scope.loaded = false;
            $scope.currentpage = page;
            var offset = page*20-20; 
            $scope.cutArray(offset);
        };  
    }); 
}]);
```

and a snippet of the Controller of the other view with pagination where it's working correctly:

```
app.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {  
    $scope.loaded = false;

    //Load and insert the page specific content
    $scope.loadpage = function(page) {
        if (page != $scope.currentpage) {
            $scope.loaded = false;
            $scope.currentpage = page;
            $scope.pubs = [];
            $scope.cities = [];
            var offset = page*20-20;
            //Get cities
            $http({...})
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.cities = data;
                //How many pages do we need?
                $http.get(...)
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.pagecount = Math.ceil(data/20);
                }); 
                //Get pubs
                $http({...})
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.pubs = data;
                    $scope.loaded = true;
                });
            });
        }
    };  
}]);
```